# Error Invalid double: "24.15" when i import data to SalesForce by Apex

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

I try to import data to SalesForce by Apex from csv file.
This is my Apex class:

```
public class AccountCsvFileUploader 
{
    public string nameFile{get;set;}
    public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
    String[] filelines = new String[]{};
    List<Account> accstoupload;

    public Pagereference ReadFile()
    {
        nameFile=contentFile.toString();
        filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
        accstoupload = new List<Account>();
        for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)    
        {
            String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
            inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Name = inputvalues[0];
            a.BillingStreet = inputvalues[3];       
            a.BILLINGCITY = inputvalues[2]; 
            a.BILLINGSTATE = inputvalues[1];
            a.PHONE = inputvalues[4];  
            a.STATUS__C = inputvalues[5];  
            a.BillingLongitude = Double.valueOf(inputvalues[6]);
            a.BillingLocation__Longitude__s = Double.valueOf(inputvalues[7]);
            a.BillingLatitude = Double.valueOf(inputvalues[8]);
            a.BillingLocation__Latitude__s= Double.valueOf(inputvalues[9]);
            a.RecordTypeId = inputvalues[10];
              a.Brick__c = inputvalues[13];
              a.ParentId = inputvalues[14];

            accstoupload.add(a);


        }
        try{
        insert accstoupload;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured. Please check the template or try again later');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
        }    
        return null;
    }

    public List<Account> getuploadedAccounts()
    {
        if (accstoupload!= NULL)
            if (accstoupload.size() > 0)
                return accstoupload;
            else
                return null;                    
        else
            return null;
    }
```

> I have error in field BillingLongitude ( and all other double fields).
>   In Csv file that fields have format "25.17". And i have error: Invalid
>   double: "24.15" from SalesForce.

String fields have imported  true. What do i must do ?

Comment: try changing the format of your number column in CSV to NUMBER.. it might be an String..

Comment: I think csv file have string format, isn't it? How can i change this column? And i used Double.valueOf to convert string to double. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: I change format in .xls file, which is a source file to csv. And I have same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Double dd = Double.valueOf('"25.17"');
System.debug(dd);
```

It throws an exception,

> Line: 1, Column: 1 System.TypeException: Invalid double: "25.17"

The problem is not with 25.17 but with "25.17"(notice the double quotes)

Which means you have to replace double quotes with blank string

```
Double dd = Double.valueOf('"25.17"'.replaceAll('"',''));
System.debug(dd);
```

In your case it would mean

```
a.BillingLongitude = Double.valueOf(inputvalues[6].replaceAll('"',''));
```

I would advice you to do null check before calling replaceAll method.